# Child scrollable container breaks parent's div width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write the following markup. On the left side I have fixed width container. On the right side I have a flexible non-scrollable container with 100% width. This flexible container contains another container with 100% width and should be scrollable once it overflows by x-axis. In my case this scrollable child container increases the width of the parent container and makes entire page scrollable even though child container is scrollable as well. I need to make scrollable only child container without breaking width of parent div. I have simplified the markup so basically it looks like this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left">
Menu
</div>
<div class="right">
 <div class="header">
  <div>
   Some text here on the left
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>
    Some button
    </button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="scrollable-container">
   <div class="item">1</div>
   <div class="item">2</div>
   <div class="item">3</div>
   <div class="item">4</div>
   <div class="item">5</div>
   <div class="item">6</div>
   <div class="item">7</div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  width: 5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.right {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.scrollable-container {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  min-width: 3em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle link just to play around. You can change the width of result frame to see the problem. It works fine until scrollable container is not overflown

https://jsfiddle.net/tmr9jsbz/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make overflow `auto`

```
scrollable-container {
    overflow: auto;
....
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working as expected. But I forgot about one thing. It doesn't work with padding of root .container. I've updated jsfiddle to show this case https://jsfiddle.net/tmr9jsbz/4/

Comment: box-sizing: border-box solves that. thanks for the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code:

```
.right {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tmr9jsbz/3/)